# Android API 23 Read_external_storage Permission Issue

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I am using the codes below. But nothing happends when I click the add photo button. Int the println's I see number 4 and number 5. Am I doing something wrong. I am using the code inside a fragment. Any help would be great.

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

// define in class
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    System.out.println("number 2");
    // We have access. Life is good.
} else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    System.out.println("number 3");
    // We've been denied once before. Explain why we need the permission, then ask again.
} else {
    System.out.println("number 4");
    // We've never asked. Just do it.
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    System.out.println("number 5");
}
```

The call back part is as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We got the permission

        System.out.println("number 6");

    } else {

        System.out.println("number 7");

        // We were not granted permission this time, so don't try to show the contact picker
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Edit:

I edite my code as below, now I see number 4, 5, 7 and 8 in the println log. No error, but nothing happens all. Shouldn't a dialog box open asking the user to give permission? I use nexus 6 with api 19 as emulator.

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 7;
// define in class

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    System.out.println("number 2");
    // We have access. Life is good.
} else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    System.out.println("number 3");
    // We've been denied once before. Explain why we need the permission, then ask again.
} else {
    System.out.println("number 4");
    // We've never asked. Just do it.
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    System.out.println("number 5");
}
```

The call back part is as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We got the permission

        System.out.println("number 6");

    } else {

        System.out.println("number 7");

        // We were not granted permission this time, so don't try to show the contact picker
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        System.out.println("number 8");
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

I did not added the permission to manifest, I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and now it seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE must be a static int with a value to in order to check more than one permission, and return a valid comparing result.

Comment: Hello Mohammad, what should be the value for MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, may you give an example about how to define it? Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: any int you want. this variable is used to distinguish between different permissions, so you need to give each request permission a different value so you can tell from which you get the response.

Comment: you may find this useful: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Mohammad thank you for the link, but I already was following it. But while using in fragments it is a bit different I guess. By the way I updated my code as above, but nothing happens now, with no error. It is reaching to the callback method, however shouldn't a dialog box open and as to give permission?

Comment: ok I did not added the permission to manifest, I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and now it seems ok. Thank you by the way.

Comment: what is the number you get from  System.out.println ? do you test the application on Marshmallow android version?